# Pytest - Good practice for reading Excel & SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I have a python application that data mines a number of server folders to extract Excel files that contain a specific cell.  From these Excel files, a SQL database is populated each month with the data from the Excel files, the files are updated on a regular basis and the database contains a monthly snapshot.

After the monthly snapshot, a graph is printed for each Excel file, using matplotlib, showing the trends over the past 12 months.

The application works fine at the moment but I would like to add some tests using pytest.

Now, is it best practice to create a sample Excel file and SQL database to run the tests against as this will provide me with some way of checking that the test results are run against consistent data, or is it typical to run tests against the live data?

Secondly, how do I test pytest to use sample data when running a test, leaving my application to use the real data the rest of the time?

Comment: If you test against live data, how will you know what the correct result should be?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking, new to test driven coding so learning the basics following completing the obeythetestinggoat site, although that focusses on Django.  Where would you place the test Excel & sql files?